# How to store data without session and cookie?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to store data without session and cookie?

For example, I store `data 1` in `page A`

I want get `data 1` in `page B` and page another

Whether it can be done without session and cookie?

Comment: you can store wherever you want: database, text file, redis, memcached etc..

Comment: pass data1 in post,get , pass it in hidden variable and get in POST or pass in quesry string and get in GET

Comment: don't you can use $_GET[]?

Answer (score 0):

If users' browsers support HTML5 then you can also store them in the client side through localStorage and sessionStorage objects and submit them to the server once needed.

Take a look at this :
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Answer (score -1):

> **You can store your data in the database.**
>
> **If you want to hold that data from one page to the second page, the**
>   **third page then you can use javascript framework like [Angular js](http://www.angularjshub.com/). You**
>   **can hold data using a $scope or $rootscope.**